# Applying a linear operator to a basis set following SVD orthonormalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-inverse, orthogonal-matrices

Define $\Phi$ as an $N$x$N$ dense, symmetric matrix, who's columns represent a set of $N$ non-orthogonal bases.

My intention is to:

1. decompose $\Phi$ via SVD:
   $U \Lambda V^T = \Phi$
2. to create it's closest orthonormal matrix: $\Psi = UV^T$

$\Psi$ will then contain an orthonormal basis set, and will be both unitary and symmetric.

I was originally using the $\Phi$ matrix as a basis set in an approximation, but the properties of the transformed $\Psi$ matrix are more suited to this task, and I believe that the basis set still spans the same space(?).

**The problem I have is** that I need to determine the values of some linear operator $\mathcal{L}(\cdot)$ acting upon whichever basis set I use. For my initial set $\Phi$ i could directly determine the value of each element in $\mathcal{L}(\Phi)$, as the basis functions have closed form descriptions to which the operator can be applied. However, I am struggling to find a route to the values of $\mathcal{L}(\Psi)$.

My current thoughts are that:

1. I know that there must exist some map $M$ that transforms $\Phi$ onto $\Psi$ such that: $\Psi=\Phi M$
2. Linear algebra tells me that I should be able to use the map to transform the operator matrix as well: $\mathcal{L}(\Psi) = \mathcal{L}(\Phi)M$
3. I also know that the inverse map $M^{-1}$ can be found by: $M^{-1}=\Psi^T\Phi $ since $\Psi$ is unitary.

If i could find the map $M$ then I think my trouble would be over. However, $\Phi$ is often very poorly conditioned, and as a result so is $M^{-1}$, so any direct matrix inversions of either matrix are out of the question.

Does anybody have any helpful ideas? Or can you point me in a useful direction for further study?

Thank you.

Comment: perhaps I am missing your point, but if you know the matrix elements $(L\Phi)_{nm}$ and $\Phi_{nm}$ in any complete orthonormal basis, then you obtain $L_{nm}$ in that basis by solving the coupled set of equations $(L\Phi)_{mk}=\sum_n L_{mn}\Phi_{nk}$. Even if that solution is difficult because of poor conditioning, I don't think there is an alternative.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks for your response. I'm not sure my initial question was clear: I know the values of $\Phi$, $\mathcal{L}(\Phi)$ and $\Psi$, and am looking to find $\mathcal{L}(\Psi)$ without solving the poorly conditioned system - if there is no alternative then that is a shame, but i'm hoping somebody might have a neat trick based on some obscure property of the SVD. As to your comment, the only basis set for which both of the pair $\Phi$ and $\mathcal{L}(\Phi)$ are known is not orthonormal.